# Callback for Console window closing (of other process), assuming the hWnd of the Console window is known

Tags: windows, winapi, console

Is there any Win32 API functions that I can use to hook into the callback of when another processes' console windows are closed? I already know the `hWnd` of the console window that is being closed.

Using `SetWinEventHook` with `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY` yields `"Invalid thread identifier. (os error 1444)"`. I am getting the `hWnd`s by monitoring foreground windows as per https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130325-00/?p=4863

Comment: `GetWindowThreadProcessId` for `ConsoleWindowClass` return not real process and thread id, but id of parent process, who create console. as result you and got `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID`. you can use for example `EVENT_CONSOLE_END_APPLICATION` for all threads/process (pass 0, 0) and compare received hwnd with your

Comment: and in any case unclear - what sense wait for console window close

Comment: It is for monitoring purposes, watching for when foreground window changes and logging them. also logs when various windows are closed, and clears all associated data with the window that my program captures.

Comment: if this case you need pass 0 in place process and thread id. if this is system wide. and why you ask about some concrete window, when you want all window create/destroy/etc notifications ?

Comment: System-wide hooks are inefficient. I already know the `hWnd` of the window I know needs to be watched for closed, so I use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get its pid and tid so that I can send it to `SetWinEventHook`

Comment: *System-wide hooks are inefficient* - really ? why you decide this ? for `EVENT_CONSOLE_END_APPLICATION` you not got many events. *for monitoring purposes, watching for when foreground window changes* - but you monitor all windows in system or only concrete ? in second case - what sense wait for it destroy ?

Comment: If the `idProcess` parameter is nonzero and `idThread` is zero, the hook function receives the specified events from all threads in that process. If the `idProcess` parameter is zero and `idThread` is nonzero, the hook function receives the specified events only from the thread specified by `idThread`. If both are zero, the hook function receives the specified events from all threads and processes.  It seems that you need to set both idProcess and idThread to 0 in order to monitor the switching of the foreground window and complete other operations afterwards.